# Runtime error while trying basic tensorflow code

Tags: python, tensorflow

Update:

Whether it is a word, sentence or phrase, The Universal Sentence Encoder will always return vector size of 512. I will like to know **why 512** and not something else.

---

The following question was resolved by the answer provided.

I tried the example provided on tensorflow home page:

https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2

I got runtime error like this:

> RuntimeError: Exporting/importing meta graphs is not supported when
>   eager execution is enabled. No graph exists when eager execution is
>   enabled.

The code that I tried is:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

config = tf.ConfigProto()
session = tf.Session(config=config)

embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2")
embeddings = embed(
    [
        "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
        "I am a sentence for which I would like to get its embedding",
    ]
)

print(session.run(embeddings))
```

How to run this code correctly?

Comment: is this question not active anymore? why don't you delete it then. or put an update at the top of it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a matter of the tensorflow version you are using.

In Tensorflow 2.0 you should use `hub.load()` or `hub.KerasLayer()`.

Comment: ValueError: Non-callable result from hub.load # Can you show how to create "session" object?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I have a follow up question. Please see the update.

Comment: @shantanuo if you have a follow up question it should be asked as its own question, you will have more luck getting an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a discussion from github: https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/350

The below solution worked for me:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_eager_execution()
```

The above code disables the eager execution.